# bar magnet inducing charge in circuit as it moves through loop

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm looking for the 2008 physics GRE and cannot figure out the reason for an answer. Here is the problem:

[image]

I would think that the current will always go from a to b as the bar goes through the loop, but the answer is actually E. Why would the induced current change directions as the magnet passes through the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer E is correct. The direction of current can be found by application of Lenz's law stating that the induced current direction is such that it opposes the cause of the induction. This means that when the south pole of the magnet approaches the loop, the induced current flows from b to a so that the magnetic field in the loop repels the approaching south pole of the magnet. After passage, when the north pole moves away from the loop, the current flows from a to b so that the magnetic field of the loop current attracts the leaving north pole.